# Sqlite query, not checking for other rows

Tags: java, sql

I have written an sql query for a java app to check if one song already exists in a db, if yes it shows the name of the song and tells that already exists, if no then it adds it in the db with another query:

```
select songs.name
from songs
inner join albums on songs.album = albums.id
inner join artist on albums.artist = artists.id
where songs.title = ?
    and albums.name = ?
    and artists.name = ?
```

The problem is that when i add 2 similar songs it works perfect it wont let me add the same song, but if I add 2 identical songs but just lets say artist different, every time i run the program it catches the first song that already exists but the second one no even though even the 2nd song exists:

```
insertSong(title: fff, artist : xxx, album: hhh); -->1 

insertSong(title: fff, artist : yyy, album: hhh); -->2
```

lets say i run the program for the first time, and it will add them, and for the second time if i run it the `-->2` song will continue to be added, no matter how many time i run the program the -->1 wont be added but the `-->2` one will even thought it is in the db. I have a perception that when it finds the `-->1` it will see the `-->2` as different and will keep putting it in the db no matter that it exists in the db. My question is how to keep searching the db even when the query finds the first match to keep searching for other matches? Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Your `where` says that a track is the same if it has the same title, album and artist. So for your query if the artist is different it is a new song. If you only want to check by title remove the `and albums.name=? AND artists.name=?`

Comment: My guess is that the artist for the second insert doesn't exist in your artists table, so the inner join fails to return them.